# Using gperftools/Heaptrack without installation

Tags: c++, unix, gperftools, heap-profiling

I am trying to do heap profiling of C++ application on unix platform. I have tried valgrind's massif but it makes application very slow and affects behavior of the application.

I was searching for other options and came across [gperftools](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/master/doc/heapprofile.html) and [heaptrack](http://milianw.de/blog/heaptrack-a-heap-memory-profiler-for-linux). Though these can be viable solution for my problem here. But I have limitation here I don't enough privileges to install these tools.

Is there any way I can setup gperftools or heaptrack without installing them in unix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always install things by specifying something like --prefix=$HOME/mygperftools to configure. Then it will install within your home directory.